# Импорт пакета ошибка ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-import

Проект имеет такую структу как на картике: Я пытаюсь импортировать из "mod.py" в "index.py"

```
from .. import mod
```

Однако  выдает ошибку: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"
Если использовать такой вариант:

```
from pack1 import mod
```

То ошибка: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pack1'"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём же проблема?

Comment: Относительный импорт не работает если запускать файл в котором он используется. Он работает только при импорте такого файла. Сам недавно бадался с этой проблемой

Comment: то есть проблема нерешаема такая? просто видел где-то примеры на youtube и читал где-то. У них вот работал относительный

Comment: Просто не использовать относительный импорт в тех файлах которые вы непосредственно запускаете.
А в тех из которых Вы импортируете что-то в тот файл который непосредственно запускаете, пожалуйста используете сколько угодно